# Adding Integers without longs

Tags: c++, math, integer, long-integer, largenumber

I am writing a class to model big integers.  I am storing my data as unsigned ints in a vector pointer called data.  What this function does is it adds n to the current big integer.  What seems to be slowing down my performance is having to use long long values.   Do any of you know a way around this.  I currently have to make sum a long long or else it will overflow.

```
void Integer::u_add(const Integer & n)
{
    std::vector<unsigned int> & tRef = *data;
    std::vector<unsigned int> & nRef = *n.data;
    const int thisSize = tRef.size();
    const int nSize = nRef.size();
    int carry = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nSize || carry; ++i)
    {
        bool readThis = i < thisSize;
        long long sum = (readThis ? (long long)tRef[i] + carry : (long long)carry) + (i < nSize ? nRef[i] : 0);
        if(readThis)
            tRef[i] = sum % BASE; //Base is 2^32
        else
            tRef.push_back(sum % BASE);
        carry = (sum >= BASE ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

Also just wondering if there is any benefit to using references to the pointers over just using the pointers themselves?  I mean should I use tRef[i] or (*data)[i] to access the data.

Comment: Are you sure `% BASE` is optimized by the compiler? Why not just use `unsigned long long sum` and do a type cast to `unsigned int`, or mask off the extra bits with a bitwise and (&)?

Comment: Why a pointer to `vector`? That's rarely appropriate; a plain `vector` should work just fine, and you won't have to deal with `new`ing and `delete`ing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using base 2^32, use base 2^30. Then when you add two values the largest sum will be 2^31-1 which fits into an ordinary `long` (signed or unsigned).

Or better still, use base 10^9 (roughly equal to 2^30), then you don't need a lot of effort to print the large numbers in decimal format.

---

If you really need to work in base 2^32, you could try a kludge like the following, provided `unsigned int`s don't throw overflow exceptions:

```
sum = term1 + term2
carry = 0
if (sum < term1 || sum < term2)
    carry = 1
```

Comment: Is `x&0x7FFFFFFF` and `x&0x80000000` faster than `x>1000000000?0:1` and `x-=k*1000000000`?  I suspect it might be.  Generally, outputting things to a screen or a file will be slow, because IO is slow: I wouldn't consider "conversion to IO format" to be important.  What you could do is have a "radix" template argument that handles adding/carry/remainder, so you can make that part modular, and swap test multiple different choices to see which is more performant...